# Dotnet-counters output from Azure App Services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to find a way to get dotnet-counters output from Azure App Services to either the Azure Portal (good enough for some trouble shooting) or some other console tool.

Does anyone know of a way to get the data, even when the app service is running across multiple app service plans?  I was picturing maybe there is an app service extension (but no luck so far).

Eventually I'll want to automate this so I can get the data onto our monitoring system, but first baby steps.... just need something I can manually eyeball to help debug issues.

Anyone have any thoughts on how to do this?

Thanks

Ken

Answer (score 0):

From offical doc, we can install `dotnet-counters` by cli command and download `.exe` directly.

As azure web app running in sandbox environment, so we can't add `dotnet-counters` to env, which means we can install it, but we can't use it.

[image]

## So my solution is,

we can download `.exe` file directly.

[image]

[image]

After downloading finished, we can copy and paste it to `wwwroot.`

[image]

**Then we can use it on scm site and azure portal.**

1. On kudu site.

   [image]
2. On azure portal.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for that info, but installation wasn't the problem but the execution of dotnet-counters. The "list" command is fine, but try running any of the others and it will (at least for me) generate errors......   try "dotnet-counters.exe ps" for example.  Does that work for you? (trying to see if it's just a ME problem or if others have same issue).

Comment: @KenFaulkner The azure web app runs in a sandbox environment. We have read and write permissions to the wwwroot folder, but not other folders. The `dotnet-counters.exe ps` command execution may involve other permissions, so it is rejected.